# MS CRM 2011:- How to allow user to delete record in iframe?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a business requirement where I need to allow the users to delete the listed record in an iframe. Let me explain it further.

I have Contract entity which is associated with user entity. We have 1:N relationship between Contract and User entity. I need to show the associated view in Contract form. I have created an iframe and set the url using JS. Until now, it looked good!.

Now, the user wants the system to allow them to delete the user from an iframe. In CRM 4.0 we used to get the delete option when we place the associated view url. However, I cannot see that option in CRM 2011.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Users can not be deleted.  Only disabled.  So the ribbon has (rightly) not offered you the delete option for the List:User tab.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a SubGrid in the form instead of a custom iframe?

You can add a subgrid to the form displaying all users related to that contract (1:N relationship entity). When you load the contract form and click on the subgrid, the ribbon will change giving you the option to add/remove related records.